# Prism: Bundle not working

Tags: web-applications, bundle, mozilla-prism

I am trying something completely new and decided to try out Webapps on Prism. I started out with the dev center on Mozilla on creating the very first bundle. It worked the first time, but once I added the other files to construct the entire bundle, Prism does not recognize my Parameters any more. Even when I tried removing all of the other files except Webapp.ini, it doesn't work anymore...

Here is my webapp.ini

```
[Parameters]
id=prismtest@educdesign.lu
name=PrismTest
uri=http://192.168.1.120/
status=no
location=no
sidebar=no
navigation=no
```

I even downloaded prism and reinstalled it on my iMac. Still, all I get is the standard form you get when no .webapp file is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you won't believe it... The error was actually somewhere else.

When I started compressing an entire structure, I selected the folder and hit compress. Now that put the folder itself at the archive's root, so the structure was compromised. I did not notice it until I found my earliest Prism try and noted the difference while uncompressing to compare.

Because I already had the folder, I continued compressing the folder, even though it had only one item (webapp.ini). The error was actually me thinking it would not take the folder into the archive.

/me gets nominated for the Internet Fail Awards